# Sorting items from one collection according to values from another collection in

Tags: mongodb, sorting, join, meteor, composite

We're making a website with Meteor. I have two MongoDB collections. One with skills:

```
[{ _id : id1 , name : "computing" } , { _id : id2 , name : "filming" } , ...]
```

and one with people:

```
[{ _id : id3 , name : "David" , knows : [...] } , { _id : id4 , name : "Laura" , knows : [...] } , ...]
```

'knows' is a list of objects that contain values between 0 and 1 that describe how well a user knows a given skill:

David's 'knows' : `[{ id : id1 , state : 0.81 } , { id : id2 , state : 0.32 }, ...]`

*I would like to show the user their skills sorted by state*. Bear in mind that every skill is not necessarily listed in each user's 'knows', only those which they have already attempted to learn.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example to get you started:

**html**

```html
<template name="myTemplate">
  {{#each people}}
    <div class="person">
      <div class="person-name">{{name}}></div>
      {{#each skills}}
        <div class="person-skill">{{name}}:{{state}}</div>
      {{/each}}
    </div>
</template>
```

**js**

```js
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  people: function() {
    // Maybe Meteor.users.find()?
    return People.find();
  },
  skills: function() {
    // here the context is a person
    return _.chain(this.knows)
      .sortBy('state')  // sort the skills in ascending order
      .map(function(skill) {
        var id = skill.id;
        // join to the skills collection through `id`
        var name = Skills.findOne(id).name;
        return {name: name, state: skill.state};
      });
  }
});
```